# Flink SQL client: SELECT 'hello world' throws [ERROR] Could not execute SQL statement

Tags: apache-flink, flink-sql

I am following Flink SQL client docs https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/table/sqlClient.html#dependencies. Opening the Flink SQL client looks fine, but `SELECT 'hello world'` doesn't work.

```
$ /data/apache/flink/flink-1.12.0/bin/sql-client.sh embedded
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/data/apache/flink/flink-1.12.0/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.12.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/data/apache/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.3/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]
No default environment specified.
Searching for '/data/apache/flink/flink-1.12.0/conf/sql-client-defaults.yaml'...found.
Reading default environment from: file:/data/apache/flink/flink-1.12.0/conf/sql-client-defaults.yaml
No session environment specified.

Command history file path: /data/home/pal-flink/.flink-sql-history
                                   ▒▓██▓██▒
                               ▓████▒▒█▓▒▓███▓▒
                            ▓███▓░░        ▒▒▒▓██▒  ▒
                          ░██▒   ▒▒▓▓█▓▓▒░      ▒████
                          ██▒         ░▒▓███▒    ▒█▒█▒
                            ░▓█            ███   ▓░▒██
                              ▓█       ▒▒▒▒▒▓██▓░▒░▓▓█
                            █░ █   ▒▒░       ███▓▓█ ▒█▒▒▒
                            ████░   ▒▓█▓      ██▒▒▒ ▓███▒
                         ░▒█▓▓██       ▓█▒    ▓█▒▓██▓ ░█░
                   ▓░▒▓████▒ ██         ▒█    █▓░▒█▒░▒█▒
                  ███▓░██▓  ▓█           █   █▓ ▒▓█▓▓█▒
                ░██▓  ░█░            █  █▒ ▒█████▓▒ ██▓░▒
               ███░ ░ █░          ▓ ░█ █████▒░░    ░█░▓  ▓░
              ██▓█ ▒▒▓▒          ▓███████▓░       ▒█▒ ▒▓ ▓██▓
           ▒██▓ ▓█ █▓█       ░▒█████▓▓▒░         ██▒▒  █ ▒  ▓█▒
           ▓█▓  ▓█ ██▓ ░▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▒              ▒██▓           ░█▒
           ▓█    █ ▓███▓▒░              ░▓▓▓███▓          ░▒░ ▓█
           ██▓    ██▒    ░▒▓▓███▓▓▓▓▓██████▓▒            ▓███  █
          ▓███▒ ███   ░▓▓▒░░   ░▓████▓░                  ░▒▓▒  █▓
          █▓▒▒▓▓██  ░▒▒░░░▒▒▒▒▓██▓░                            █▓
          ██ ▓░▒█   ▓▓▓▓▒░░  ▒█▓       ▒▓▓██▓    ▓▒          ▒▒▓
          ▓█▓ ▓▒█  █▓░  ░▒▓▓██▒            ░▓█▒   ▒▒▒░▒▒▓█████▒
           ██░ ▓█▒█▒  ▒▓▓▒  ▓█                █░      ░░░░   ░█▒
           ▓█   ▒█▓   ░     █░                ▒█              █▓
            █▓   ██         █░                 ▓▓        ▒█▓▓▓▒█░
             █▓ ░▓██░       ▓▒                  ▓█▓▒░░░▒▓█░    ▒█
              ██   ▓█▓░      ▒                    ░▒█▒██▒      ▓▓
               ▓█▒   ▒█▓▒░                         ▒▒ █▒█▓▒▒░░▒██
                ░██▒    ▒▓▓▒                     ▓██▓▒█▒ ░▓▓▓▓▒█▓
                  ░▓██▒                          ▓░  ▒█▓█  ░░▒▒▒
                      ▒▓▓▓▓▓▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒░░▓▓  ▓░▒█░

    ______ _ _       _       _____  ____  _         _____ _ _            _  BETA
   |  ____| (_)     | |     / ____|/ __ \| |       / ____| (_)          | |
   | |__  | |_ _ __ | | __ | (___ | |  | | |      | |    | |_  ___ _ __ | |_
   |  __| | | | '_ \| |/ /  \___ \| |  | | |      | |    | | |/ _ \ '_ \| __|
   | |    | | | | | |   <   ____) | |__| | |____  | |____| | |  __/ | | | |_
   |_|    |_|_|_| |_|_|\_\ |_____/ \___\_\______|  \_____|_|_|\___|_| |_|\__|

        Welcome! Enter 'HELP;' to list all available commands. 'QUIT;' to exit.


Flink SQL> SELECT 'Hello World';
[ERROR] Could not execute SQL statement. Reason:
org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobSubmissionException: Failed to submit JobGraph.
```

Any help? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There needs to be a Flink session cluster available to the SQL client on which it can run the jobs created by your queries. See the [Getting Started](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/table/sqlClient.html#getting-started) section of the SQL Client documentation for more info:

> The SQL Client is bundled in the regular Flink distribution and thus runnable out-of-the-box. It requires only a running Flink cluster where table programs can be executed. For more information about setting up a Flink cluster see the [Cluster & Deployment](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/deployment/resource-providers/standalone/) part. If you simply want to try out the SQL Client, you can also start a local cluster with one worker using the following command:
>
> `./bin/start-cluster.sh`

Comment: Gotcha. The reason why it throws exception in my case: we run Flink on Yarn rather than on local cluster. That's why I didn't run the ./bin/start-cluster.sh script in the computer. It sounds what I need is SQL Client Gateway. Thank you.

Comment: No, you don't necessarily need a gateway. You can just configure the client to know where the session cluster is. But there is a gateway -- https://github.com/ververica/flink-sql-gateway -- if you want to use one.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using EMR, note that a Flink cluster is not started automatically for you.

From [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/flink-create-cluster.html) we can see that an EMR Step is added to spin up a Flink cluster in the background using `flink-yarn-session -d` before running Flink jobs.

`/usr/bin/flink-yarn-session` is a wrapper around `/lib/flink/bin/yarn-session.sh`. It is used to start a Flink cluster on YARN.

Flink clusters can run on YARN, K8s, or run as a standalone cluster.